# Github alternative to force push

Tags: github

We have a dev branch in the team. I want to remove HEAD~9 commit from the dev branch as it was an accidental merge from a feature branch. I don't want to rewrite history as it might lead to problems with working copies of other developers. What other alternatives do I have?

One alternative that I thought is to branch off from dev, remove the commit from that branch, and then merge the new branch to dev. Can this lead to any problem later?

Comment: I think [revert](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) is what you're looking for. (see "Reverting a Merge")

Comment: @EvgenySoynov Will I be able to do this without rewriting history in dev branch?

Comment: revert does not rewrite history. It will create "reverse" commit to undo merge.